# Zend Framework and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, zend-framework

Is it possible to take advantage of SQL Server in Zend Framework? I tried run my zend server with `pdo_mssql`, `sqlserver` and `odbc` and failed each time.

Did you manage to use SQL Server in your project?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the [SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do use MSSQL.

Example:

```
private function init()
{
    $this->db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql(array(
    'host'     => 'mssqlserver.com',
    'username' => 'dude',
    'password' => 'superman',
    'dbname'   => 'cooldata'
    ));
}
```